# If I try to sell tokens from a smart contract, it is failing with insufficient output amount

Tags: solidity, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am trying to do an autosell function like safemoon has, but I am getting always "insufficient output amount"

Steps to reproduce:

1. Deploy my token
2. Add liquidity v2 in uniswap with 1 T tokens, 1 ETH
3. Try to buy my token

```
    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        // Please notice that this is not the total of the tokens, only what I have received as part
        // of the sale, since this is only for selling
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);

        // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
        // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
        // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
        // has been manually sent to the contract
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for ETH
        swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

        // how much ETH did we just swap into?
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

        // add liquidity to uniswap
        //addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint)
    {
        IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
        ERC20 token1 = ERC20(pair.token1());
        (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();
    
        // decimals
        uint res0 = Res0*(10**token1.decimals());
        return((amount*res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) public {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pancakeswap_router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(pancakeswap_router), tokenAmount);

        uint256 minimumAccepted = getTokenPrice(uniswapV2Pair, tokenAmount).mul(90).div(100); //10% slippage
        // make the swap
        pancakeswap_router.swapExactTokensForETH(
            tokenAmount,
            minimumAccepted,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/rinkeby/0x7c7c72a0fc47b5b5828e1ee468b9889562d9579533d9e06b1ce32cf9672bb6a7/debugger?trace=0.4.1

Any clue why function swapExactTokensForETH is always failing?
I have also tried to send minimum eth = 0 but I have the same issue

Edit: if I change the minimum to 0, I am getting the same error but in a different place: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/rinkeby/0xb4f2f3c1bee3fb9ed9fbfda0fce42b2175ec935d3bd55b9bc7156b9e03f25ea0/debugger?trace=0.4.3.2

Comment: You are probably trying to buy the entire portion of the tokens in the pool, of course, you can't do that. try buying a very small portion of your token like a 20th of a token

Comment: Hi, I am just trying to buy arround 1 million over 1 T of the supply

Comment: there is not enough tokens int eh pool, you can not buy

Comment: Irrelevant unless the liquidity pool is literally empty. @DiegoGomez can you verify the contract on etherscan? would make the tx easier to follow on tenderly

Comment: @Foxxxey I have reuploaded the code with all the info requested:


contract: 0x9e384e37609000fa220bd18c548f3911e8969453


transaction:
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/Diegogomez87/luckyluna/tx/rinkeby/0xc1e23d549c5f678839057354363acb685d033171d383893b0cc9caaf68c4b6c2/debugger?trace=0.4.2.3.2